How to read XML and then encode it in Base64 with padding avoiding strange characters
I am writing a TypeScript code and I would like to read an XML file, to then encode it in Base64 with padding. I could read and encode the file, but after decoding it, I see many strange characters which I don't want.
The XML file I have is the one below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DataContent xmlns="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns6="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns5="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns8="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns7="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns9="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns11="http://somecontent.com/somecontent/1_1" xmlns:ns10="http://vcg.somecontent.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns4="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" schemaVersion="2.7">
    <Status>
        <DataCompleted/>
    </Status>
    <Messages>
        <Message>
            <ReasonCode>33</ReasonCode>
            <ReasonDesc>Info:</ReasonDesc>
            <ReasonDesc>Val = 2</ReasonDesc>
            <ReasonDesc>BLE = 1234567890</ReasonDesc>
            <ReasonDesc>BLA = SOMETHING 12345</ReasonDesc>
        </Message>
    </Messages>
    <DataContentOutputs>
        <DataContentOutput>
            <Inputs>
                <Input>
                    <InputVal schemaVersion="2.1" InputCode="BLAP2">
                        <ns5:Val>
                            <ns4:Bool>true</ns4:Bool>
                        </ns5:Val>
                    </InputVal>
                </Input>
            </Inputs>
            <FailedInputs/>
        </DataContentOutput>
    </DataContentOutputs>
</DataContent> 

I am using the code below to read the file as a string, format the XML:
const stringFileContent= fs.readFileSync(filePathGoesHere, 'utf-8')
const xmlFileContent = xmlFormat(stringFileContent, {
            indentation: '  ', 
            collapseContent: true, 
            lineSeparator: '\r\n'
        })

While debugging the code, this is the value I get in xmlFileContent variable:
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\r\n <DataContent xmlns="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns6="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns5="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns8="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns7="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns9="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns11="http://somecontent.com/somecontent/1_1" xmlns:ns10="http://vcg.somecontent.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns4="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" schemaVersion="2.7">\r\n  <Status>\r\n    <DataCompleted/>\r\n  </Status>\r\n  <Messages>\r\n  …Desc>BLE = 1234567890</ReasonDesc>\r\n      <ReasonDesc>BLA = SOMETHING 12345</ReasonDesc>\r\n    </Message>\r\n  </Messages>\r\n  <DataContentOutputs>\r\n    <DataContentOutput>\r\n      <Inputs>\r\n        <Input>\r\n          <InputVal schemaVersion="2.1" InputCode="BLAP2">\r\n            <ns5:Val>\r\n              <ns4:Bool>false</ns4:Bool>\r\n            </ns5:Val>\r\n          </InputVal>\r\n        </Input>\r\n      </Inputs>\r\n      <FailedInputs/>\r\n    </DataContentOutput>\r\n  </DataContentOutputs>\r\n</DataContent>'

Then I encode the above XML in Base64 with padding, using the code below:
const xmlEncoded = this.xmlEncodeBase64WithPadding(xmlFileContent)

   private xmlEncodeBase64WithPadding(content: any){
        const encodedBytes = Buffer.from(content, 'utf-8').toString('base64');
        let encodedStr = encodedBytes;

        // Add padding if necessary
        const paddingNeeded = encodedStr.length % 4;
        if (paddingNeeded) {
            encodedStr += '='.repeat(4 - paddingNeeded);
        }

        return encodedStr;
    } 
        

The thing is that, when I get the encode result and decode it using Notepad++, I can see strange characters like this, which I saw are caused by binaries, but which I could not solve and I would like to avoid them:
熖煆V%Ǘ5&W7VǇ3У´FF6ö熖煦W÷'C

This is the complete encoded result:
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/Pg0KPERhdGFDb250ZW50IHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vZXN3LnZsdi5jb20vc29tZWNvbnRlbnQiIHhtbG5zOm5zNj0iaHR0cDovL2Vzdy52bHYuY29tL3NvbWVjb250ZW50IiB4bWxuczpuczU9Imh0dHA6Ly9lc3cudmx2LmNvbS9zb21lY29udGVudCIgeG1sbnM6bnM4PSJodHRwOi8vZXN3LnZsdi5jb20vc29tZWNvbnRlbnQiIHhtbG5zOm5zNz0iaHR0cDovL2Vzdy52bHYuY29tL3NvbWVjb250ZW50IiB4bWxuczpuczk9Imh0dHA6Ly9lc3cudmx2LmNvbS9zb21lY29udGVudCIgeG1sbnM6bnMxMT0iaHR0cDovL3NvbWVjb250ZW50LmNvbS9zb21lY29udGVudC8xXzE…AgICAgICAgICAgIDxJbnB1dFZhbCBzY2hlbWFWZXJzaW9uPSIyLjEiIElucHV0Q29kZT0iQkxBUDIiPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPG5zNTpWYWw+DQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPG5zNDpCb29sPmZhbHNlPC9uczQ6Qm9vbD4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvbnM1OlZhbD4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9JbnB1dFZhbD4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L0lucHV0Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9JbnB1dHM+DQogICAgICAgICAgICA8RmFpbGVkSW5wdXRzLz4NCiAgICAgICAgPC9EYXRhQ29udGVudE91dHB1dD4NCiAgICA8L0RhdGFDb250ZW50T3V0cHV0cz4NCjwvRGF0YUNvbnRlbnQ+IA==
And this is the xml after decoding it in Notepad++:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DataContent xmlns="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns6="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns5="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns8="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns7="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns9="http://esw.vlv.com/somecontent" xmlns:ns11="http://somecontent.com/somecontent/1_1¦Ė燗Ef66V֕fW'6ö㒣"㒢燗D6öFSҤ$ĕ"#ТƧ3S¥fàТƧ3C¤&ööæfǶS¶糃¤&ööàТ¶糓¥fàТ´燗EfàТ´燗CТ´燗G3ТĦƖD燗G2´FF6ö熖焷WGWCТ´FF6ö熖焷WGWG3У´FF6ö熖烢 

VERY IMPORTANT
I suspect this is regarding some configuration.
As I could make it to work using another repository.
However I still need to run this code on the repository which does not generates the correct encoded value.
Do you know if any configuration or package version may cause this?
My project is built in PlayWright + TypeScript + Cucumber.

Does results match the original file?  Are all the characters different or just some?  Use Beyond compare to check original and results.  Normally when Base 64 is decoded you will get errors if the file was not a valid base 64 string.

Hi jdweng,
I edited my question, including more information.

My Notepad++ is set for UTF-8 mode and also getting unprintable characters like STX and ETX.  When I try with Note++ using STRICT option it fails.  Also fails when trying to decode in c#.  I think the Base64 string is corrupt.  Try comparing the Base64 string where it was generated against the string you posted.  I think the string is corrupted.

Hi @jdweng, after many tests I could see this is the case.
when i encode and then decode it in the same place, it works fine, but do you have any suggestion of what I could do to solve this?
But the strangest thing is that when this same code is run in others machine it works as it should.

You're trying to read a XML file in xmlString format. Please use the code as follows:
function readXMLFile(filePath: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject('Error reading XML file: ' + err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

You complete code should be:
const filePath = './data/sampledata.xml';
readXMLFile(filePath)
    .then((xmlString) => {
        // console.log(xmlString);
        try {
            // Use Your function for XML String encoding
            // console.log(xmlEncodeBase64WithPadding(xmlString));

            // Alternative way
            const base64String = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(xmlString)));
            const paddedBase64 = base64String.padEnd(Math.ceil(base64String.length / 4) * 4, '=');
            console.log(paddedBase64);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error encoding XML to Base64:', error);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

This giving response as follows:
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
Working properly, tested from: https://www.base64decode.org/
Package.json
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prod": "node ./dist/index.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "tsc": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }

and tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",    
    "module": "commonjs",  
    "moduleResolution": "node10",                    
    "baseUrl": "./src",                              
    "typeRoots": ["./@types", "./node_modules/@types", "./types"], 
    "sourceMap": true,                               
    "outDir": "dist",                                 
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}


Thanks, @ArtBindu.
But the code you provided also didn't work for me.
I think there is something to do with some configuration or the way Playwright + Typescript works. As you can check below, the code you provided for me generated the encode below: Sorry, could not post here, too long.

add Package.json config. Please use it

Updated my package.json with the one you shared, but still same result.

@Chewie you're working in typescript project. So, configure the TypeScript compiler accordingly

share your typescript compiler @Chewie

Sorry by my lack of knowledge, but where can I find it?

Please learn basic of node.js & typescript project

Found how to check it, just need to run tsc -v.
If you want the tsc version, this is the one I am using: Version 5.1.6.

thats not an issue ...

create a simple typescript/node.js project and test with that ... it work properly ...

or share a sample project to understand

Yes, I know, check my comments on my question.
I already did as you suggested, created another project and run the same code. On the other project it does work fine, but the thing is that I need to run this code in the project that is not working. That's why I believe it is a configuration issue.

Please share a demo project to understand the issue. You're question is not sufficient to understand the issue.
